# Getting rid of redundant reference to owner in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

I have these entities in JPA + Hibernate, `Player` and `AvatarAttributeOwnership`. The former has a `Set` of the latter, which defines which avatar attributes it owns.

```
@Entity
public class Player implements Serializable {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="owner",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AvatarAttributeOwnership> ownedAvatarAttributes;

    ...

}


@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"owner","gender","type","attrId"}))
public class AvatarAttributeOwnership implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="owner")
    private Player owner;

    // these three columns define the attribute (i.e. are attribute's key)
    @Column
    private String attrId;

    @Column
    private String gender;

    @Column
    private String type;

    @Column
    private Date ownedSince;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + attrId.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + gender.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + owner.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + type.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        AvatarAttributeOwnership other = (AvatarAttributeOwnership) obj;

        if (!attrId.equals(other.attrId)) return false;
        if (gender != other.gender) return false;
        if (!owner.equals(other.owner)) return false;
        if (!type.equals(other.type)) return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

AvatarAttributeOwnerships are created like this:

```
                player = em.find(Player.class, playerId);
                player.getAvatarAttributeOwnership().add(new AvatarAttributeOwnership(player, attrId, gender, type, new Date())); 
                em.persist(player);
```

Can I get rid of the owner reference in `AvatarAttributeOwnership` while keeping the unique constraint defined there?

Answer (score 0):

You can, by defining a unidirectional many to one association. This will generate a join table with a column for the id of the owner (Player in your case) and another column with the id of the children (AvatarAttributeOwnership). See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-12m for the explanation (notice the unique=true in the mapping)

Comment: I may have abbreviated my sample code too much. I've expanded it.

Comment: Bart: Notice the type of association I mentioned is different from yours: It's many-to-many with unique=true. I myself used it as described in the link I provided and I didn't have to hold an owner attribute in the children. I just needed to define the relation in the owner: Owner o1 = new Owner(); o1.children.add(new Child()); Child doesn't have any owner reference and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define a unique constraint on column '`order`' this column has obviously to be present in the corresponding table. So you can't get rid of the reference *and* keep the constraint.
What you could do is to store only the primary key of `Player` in `AvatarAttributeOwnership` but why should you? In case you wonder about any overhead for loading a Player instance for the creating of an AvatarAttributeOwnership instance: you could always pass `em.getReference(Player.class, playerId)` instead of a real player instance which doesn't trigger a database select unless you access any Player state in the constructor of AvatarAttributeOwnership.

Comment: The unique constraint is there to prevent players from owning the same attribute twice. However the difficulty is that each attribute is defined by 3 values, not one.

Comment: But how can you expect to be able to define a constraint on columns you don't map in any way? After all JPA is about O/R mapping...

Comment: Turns out what I really wanted was to make `AvatarAttributeOwnership` embeddable, and have collection of it in `Player`. That generates a table with a column `Player_id`, without having it in the class. The uniqueness is handled by `Set` and `equals` though, not by the database, which is ok but not ideal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814874/insert-to-jpa-collection-without-loading-it for the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I really wanted is to make `AvatarAttributeOwnership` `@Embeddable`.